# Dialog boxes that are cut off, any easy fixes for them?

Tags: modal-dialog, item-styles

On several dialog boxes such as the "add document" dialog in SharePoint we are encountering a situation where the dialog is too small to see the "Submit" buttons in the dialog.  While end user education has been able to tackle this for the most part, we're wondering if there's a quicker fix to override height and width of all dialogs by default.  Some initial searching didn't reveal any stylesheets in charge of this.  Any ideas out there?

Comment: Are you using a custom master page?

Comment: Nope, we're mostly out of the box.  Custom logo and some theme changes but not much else.

Comment: I've noticed this before too and haven't really found a good solution other than clicking the maximize button.

Comment: I have the same issue. Any resolution?

Comment: See this link--I think it solves your problem:
https://kyleschaeffer.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-2010-pop-up-dialogs/

Comment: If you can, best practice is to always try and summarize the solution when you provide a link. This helps if the link ever goes dead, so that the solution is still recorded here. Thanks for your contribution